# Delayed div display within an if statement (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I need to trigger a delayed display of a div after another event is triggered.

So in this case the user selects an option from a dropdown menu which will load a set of questions. Upon this action (whilst the set of questions is loading), I want to display a div containing Submit and Cancel buttons 5 seconds after - the reason for the delay is so that if the questions take a second or two to load the user can't click Submit before them loading.

Here is the code for the questions loading:

```
  if (val) {
    // AJAX up some questions...
    $('#questions').load('/registration/questions/'+val);
  } else {
    $('#questions').html("");
  }
```

Here is the code I tried for delaying the div display which worked for when the page loaded but I need it to work after the if (val) is activated:

```
function showButtons() {
    document.getElementById("delay-buttons").style.display = "block";
}
// adjust this as needed, 1 sec = 1000
setTimeout("showButtons()", 5000);
```

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the case of calling the `setTimeout` right after the condition is true, and otherwise clear the `timeout`?

Comment: @MelanciaUK Sorry I'm not too great with JS...

I changed the code so that it showed the div upon the event and that works great (code below), I just need to add the delay now but I have no idea of how to integrate that. Code: document.getElementById("delay-buttons").style.display = "block";

Comment: If you're playing with the layout just when the AJAX call is completed, you should do all of this within the `complete` event of this call. It's an asynchronous call, so it won't wait until it's finished to carry on in the code, thus will change the layout prematurely (likely).

Comment: Do the buttons have to show exactly 5 seconds after the user selects the option, regardless of how quickly or slowly the questions load? Or would it be feasible to show the buttons immediately after the questions load? That can be done by passing a callback function as a 2nd argument to the call to the `load` function. See http://api.jquery.com/load/ for details.